# Why Facebook preview image is not showing up?

Tags: php, facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, hyperlink

I have developed news page in my site and my client want to post the news from my site to

facebook and when he paste news link on the facebook, ideally it should create a facebook

post preview which load snapshot of news and also it populates image [if that page contains any image] in that snapshot.

I have searched on google and I found that I need use https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ and I have used that facebook tool and I found that image is not grabbed while creating snapshot.

Now please someone tell me that what I can do to get image in preview of fb post.

Here is link which is having image in his content but still is not visible in preview.

[this link](http://bevforce.com/news-room/industry-interviews/supplier-spotlight/supplier-spotlight-nick-ziccardi) is having image but when I this link on fb, it is not showing up image.

As news are get created automatically, I can add any meta tag because its static solution but I am using news feed which automatically creates new pages.

So I am not expecting any static solution

Comment: You should use og tags for this. [see here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects) and [see this also](http://davidwalsh.name/demo/facebook-metas.php)

Comment: The problem is that your og:image url contains spaces. Remove them

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are not able to see an image preview is because there is no open graph object specified on that page. For example, you need to add this :

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://bevforce.com/sites/default/files/2014-07-31%2003.59.57.jpg"> in your header.
```

More information about open graph object on [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/tutorials/scrumptious/open-graph-object).